# Control iSight indicator light on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, webcam

I am hoping to use the iSight camera's indicator light (the green light that indicates power to the camera) as an indicator for some kind of task, be it new mail, job is done running, etc.

Anyone know the front door for accessing something like that?

Comment: I've been looking for a kext or other tool that would light the camera lamp while the microphone was listening, too. If you ever come up with something like that, let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article on macosxhints would seem to be heading the direction you're going: [Take iSight snapshots during invalid login attempts](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2006120918170984) insofar as it's controlling the camera.

Then there's Apple's own [Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Hardware/Conceptual/iSightProgGuide/index.html)

See also

> [Linux iSight audio driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lisight/) (ALSA). This driver works only with the ieee1394 (firewire) iSight digital camera. It will not work with the iSight shipped "embedded" with the new intel-mac series (macbook, macbook-pro, imac)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I realize the command line interface that is used, `isightcapture`, doesn't work (since 10.4), but DOES activate the light momentarily. I can use that broken command to trigger a signal! I feel very dirty... but it does what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its doubtful. This is most likely controlled by the camera itself when it is recording.